# Как удалить все строки, в столбце которой содержится определенное слово/фраза?

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет, только недавно начал пользоваться и учить python. Хочу понять, как мне удалить все строки, в которых содержится слово 'реф' в столбце 'тип авто'. Удалить нужно до строки сортировки.

Код прикладываю:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('PythonТарифы2.xlsx')
xl = pd.ExcelFile('PythonТарифы2.xlsx')
print(xl.sheet_names)
df1 = xl.parse('Лист3')
df1.sort_values(by=['прямой (руб без НДС) О', 'Дата действия от'], ascending=[True, False], inplace = True)
df1.drop_duplicates(subset='ОткудаКудаПаллет', keep="first", inplace = True)
df1.to_excel('МинимальныеТарифыPythonP2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот хочу вам помочь, читаю ваш вопрос *"Хочу понять, как мне удалить все строки, в которых содержится слово `'реф'` в столбце `'тип авто'`.*" Покажите мне в вашем скрипте, где вы не то что работаете, а хотя-бы упоминаете  столбец 'тип авто'?   Долго думал над фразой *`Удалить нужно до строки сортировки`*. И не мог понять, какая строка сортировки может быть в той таблице, из которой надо что-то удалять.  Вам не жаловаться надо, `"я только начинаю учить python, пожалейте меня"`. Вам надо учиться точно и аккуратно описывать проблему, если хотите получить помощь.

Отвечаю только потому, что это ваш первый вопрос на форуме, а к новичкам надо относиться (на первых порах) лояльно, нежно и трепетно.

В общем, поскольку вам лень аккуратно писать свой вопрос -  мне лень аккуратно писать на него ответ. Поэтому вот вам пример, как из датафрейма "удалить строки, в которых содержится слово `'реф'` в столбце `'тип авто'`"

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'тип авто':['qqq','ttt','реф','uuu','реф','sss','реф'],
                                                 'C':[i for i in np.random.random(7)]})
```

В датафрейме находиться

```
   A тип авто         C
0  1      qqq  0.962045
1  2      ttt  0.953155
2  3      реф  0.508149
3  4      uuu  0.565687
4  5      реф  0.298825
5  6      sss  0.261208
6  7      реф  0.859682
```

Удаляем

Вариант 1.

```
df=df.loc[df['тип авто'] != 'реф']
```

Вариант 2.

```
df.drop(np.where(df['тип авто'] == 'реф')[0],inplace=True)
```

Результат в обоих случаях, как и ожидалось, тождественен:

```
   A тип авто         C
0  1      qqq  0.962045
1  2      ttt  0.953155
3  4      uuu  0.565687
5  6      sss  0.261208
```

Ну, а до какой строчки вам надо вставлять код и прочие тюнингование под вашу задачу -  оставляю на самостоятельную работу.